# Format Form Validation Message in Laravel 5

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

How to format form validation error message in laravel 5 like below ??

The **Date** is not a valid date.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `<strong>` round a custom message? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-error-messages or try http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#working-with-error-messages

Comment: I tried  with wrapping <strong> and I visited those 2 links but none of these  could not give me solution. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can set custom validation messages in the **resources/lang/en/validation.php** file:

```
'custom' => [
    'date' => [
        'date' => 'The <strong>:attribute</strong> is not a valid date.',
    ],
],
```

If you want the attribute to be bold on *all* date validation messages (regardless of the field name), then you can set the message for the `date` key:

```
'date' => 'The <strong>:attribute</strong> is not a valid date.',
```

Answer (score 0):

use str_replace and then ask  blade to parse the output as an html text, like this:

```
{!! str_replace( 'Date' , '<b>Date</b>' , 'The Date is not a valid date')  !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [basic validation error display](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) and want to show the name of the field in bold, you can:

Using the 'en' language as an example.

- Add the name of the field in a language file (resources/lang/en/validation.php) inside the attributes key:

  ```
  <?php
  return [
      'attributes' => [
          'my_field' => '<b>My Field</b>'
      ]
  ];
  ```
- In the validation message display, just change the {{ $error }} to {!! $error !!}